# How does one say "in the range of" notationally?

Tags: notation

If I wanted to express that $|V|$ (the number of vertices for a problem) was in the range of 50 to 75; how should I go about doing this using correct notation?

is

$|V| = (50,75)$

correct? or should it be more like set notation?

$|V| \in (50,75)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$50 \le |V| \le 75$ (or $<$ if that's what you meant).

Comment: This is the most unambiguous way of writing such a thing.

Comment: thanks, i realised that about 5 mins after i posted my question! sometimes you just need to vocalise your problem to get your brain moving..